# Is there a way to show popovers only on click of Slider dots in react-slick?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, frontend, mouseevent, react-slick

I am using Slider component  from "react-slick", and  wanted to show popovers only when users click on Slider dots, tried **afterChange, beforeChange** setting props, but that does not worked, it is like popovers should only appears when user click on any of the slider dots.
[[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Fr2y8.png)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eY97S.png)

I tried For all available methods but that did not worked for me,

Comment: Can you share some of the code as a starting point?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.